# How to disable the first item on a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, jcombobox

I understand the question has been asked many times, but on a serious note. what is the easiest way to disable the first item of a JComboBox in Java. I have the following code and I want to disable "Select a State" so it forces the user to pick a state, if they don't then it prints a blank string

```
  states = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"Select a State",
      "AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","FL","GA",
        "HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD",
        "MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ",
        "NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC",
        "SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY"});
  states.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple basically you can just use `conditional` statement :

```
   states.addItemListener(
        new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                 // now there's nothing happen when we select the first item
                if(states.getSelectedIndex()>0){ 
                    System.out.println("YOU CLICK INDEX-"+states.getSelectedIndex());
               }
            }
        }
        );
```

So when the user click the first item , there's nothing can happen. Here is the complete demo :

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBoxDemo extends JFrame {
   private JComboBox<String> states;

public ComboBoxDemo() {
    super("JComboBox Demo");
    states = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"Select a State",
        "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
        "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
        "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
        "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
        "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"});

    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    add(states, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    states.addItemListener(
    new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            // now there's nothing happen when we select the first item
            if(states.getSelectedIndex()>0){
                System.out.println("YOU CLICK INDEX- "+states.getSelectedIndex());
           }
        }
    }
    );                     
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ComboBoxDemo g = new ComboBoxDemo();
    g.setVisible(true);
    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
 }
 }
```

Comment: instead of using if(states.getSelectedIndex > 0). I've used == . therefore it prompts a warning dialog to the user!. Works perfectly kudos!

Comment: Just modify it according to your taste :P

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Combo Box Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/). It will display message when no item is selected in the combo box.